# SemanticUI jquery is not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

Here are the relevant parts in my code to the problem:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/semantic/dist/semantic.rtl.min.css" />
    <?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
    <script src="/static/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/semantic/dist/components/dropdown.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.ui.dropdown')
            .dropdown()
        ;
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="ui dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="gender">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Gender</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="male">Male</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="female">Female</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

It seems like the dropdown just refuses to work. I've tried other things as well (search, accordion) and they haven't worked as well.

Checked on different browsers, on different platforms, and nothing.

Checked also maybe there's a problem with loading the files, but according to Chrome everything loads fine and there're no errors.

Comment: @Timing No, console is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `.ui.dropdown` element on the page when you are invoking `dropdown` plugin. You need to initialize it when DOM is ready:

```
$(function() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

Or you could also put your original script block before closing `</body>` tag, it would work too.

Comment: @Dr.Boo And it was "Timing No"?